# How do I refactor a controller utilizing a service to controller as format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller I would like to convert to controller as format, but my attempts are running into a wall.

Is there anything special I need to do since it is utilizing a service?

```
app.controller("ReplicatedCtrl", function($scope, ReplicatedService) {
  ReplicatedService.getSomeData().then(function(result) {
    var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
    var refSubdomain = parts.shift();

    $scope.coach = result;
    $scope.coach.refUrl = refSubdomain;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller("ReplicatedCtrl", function(ReplicatedService) {
  var ctrl = this;
  ReplicatedService.getSomeData().then(function(result) {
    var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
    var refSubdomain = parts.shift();

    ctrl.coach = result;
    ctrl.coach.refUrl = refSubdomain;
  });
```

Then in template use:

```
{{ctrl.coach}}
```

If you used `controllerAs: 'ctrl'`, or  `controller: 'ReplicatedCtrl as ctrl'`